# Quill : multiple editors, how to know which one called a specific Embed blot?

Tags: editor, quill

I have a few Quill editors open at the same time and defined a custom blot (Embed). Now, I would like this blot to behave a little differently when in a specific editor or another. For various reasons, it is very complicated to define two different blot classes, so is there a way for an embed to know which editor is actually concerned by its construction ? From inside the blot, I don't know how to determine the calling editor.
I tried the editor that has the focus, but then it doesn't work when trying to setContents programmatically.

Thanks for any help

Damir

Answer (score 0):

Replying to myself, I send to the blot a JSON string of the object(s), the blot taking care of the JSON parsing. Seems to work.